# Will a wireless usb keyboard work with android smartphone

Tags: wi-fi, usb, keyboard

I have a samsung A10 android 10 smartphone. I intend to buy a On The Go USB adapter and plug in the Keyboard adapter that is usually connected to my laptop so i can use my wireless keyboard and mouse with my smartphone, will the android OS recognize and accept this operation, Thank You for your time and effort

Comment: It should. I once used a mouse with an android device and even that worked fine

Comment: You used an OTG cable and then plugged in the keyboard adapter?

Comment: Yes, I used the OTG connector cable.

Comment: Okay Thanks lemme execute then, lets hope it will work

Comment: As long as the USB wireless adapter does not require any special drives or tools on host side this should work (it just have to register as USB HID device). When it comes to wireless keyboards most people directly use a Bluetooth keyboard as all Android phones have built in Bluetooth.